# Move Wordpress Webroot

Tags: wordpress

Currently, I'm working on a WordPress blog installed at the root and all posts are in a 'blog' category such that the blog essentially lives at /blog.

I'm implementing a custom app for the main site so I would like to move the blog from living in the webroot to living in a subfolder called 'blog'. This would make it so that the blog still lives at /blog, but my app can now live in the webroot.

What steps must I take to move the blog from the webroot to a folder called 'blog'? Moving the files is easy, but what changes must I make to the WordPress db to support the change?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go into the steps, but it's much better explained on the following site:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress